# dynamically create variable from variable names

Tags: javascript

I have a dynamic number of files (structure, tab1, tab2, tab3, ...) that I load into my site. 
For each of them I want to define variables like "total", "different", ....

```
dbVariables.structure.total = aaa
dbVariables.tab1.total = 123
dbVariables.tab2.total = 456
dbVariables. ... .total = xx

dbVariables.structure.different= aaa
dbVariables.tab1.different = abc;
dbVariables.tab2.different = def;
dbVariables. ... .different = xxx
```

Since putting them to [window] is not nice, i created dbVariables Object to store the variables there. I currently have a for loop that loads the files and I can even create dbVariable.tab1, dbVariable.tab2 etc. dynamically, but how would I stitch the last peace of information to it to?

```
var dbVariables= {};
for (i=0; i< fileNamesArray.length; i++){
    filename = fileNamesArray[i];
    processData(filename);
}
});
// the ".total" is not accepted :-(
function processData(filename){
    dbVariables[filename].total = 123;
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by "is not accepted"?

Comment: It means global variables aren't a good idea, which is true.

Comment: Can you please fix the typos in your code? It's makes it a lot easier for people to understand your question without having to guess if `processData` and `processDatra` are the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this:

```
dbVariables[filename].total = 123;
```

Because there is no `dbVariables[filename]`, so you can set a property on undefined. You need to add it first.

```
function processData(filename){
    dbVariables[filename] = {};
    dbVariables[filename].total = 123;
};
```

But you might be better off if `dbVariables` was an array rather than an object unless you are certain that there are no duplicate `filename`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `dbVariables[filename]` before adding the total. try something like that :

```
function processDatra(filename){
    if(typeof dbVariables[filename] === 'undefined') dbVariables[filename] = {};
    dbVariables[filename].total = 123;
};
```